# Why are some fields in JSON output missing quotes and why no double quotes in output

Tags: javascript, json

Below is screenshot of vs code terminal output.  The JSON output is treating the 3 fields with red arrows differently than the others. The string has double quotes around easch item but tje JSOn.parse output has single quotes' For test purposes, code is set to handle 1 listing.

[image]

Here is code

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const fs = require('fs');
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

fs.readFile('./data/hb2019.html', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  const dom = new JSDOM(data);

  fieldName = [];
  fieldName = [...dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('#tableComparableSales >tbody .salesReportSortLink')]


  //file may artificially have multiple pages


  var listings = [];// array of raw listing links
  listings = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('[id^=tdSales]');
  //var output = '[';
  var output = '';
  (function () {
    field = [];
    //console.log(listings.length)
    var numListings = 1;//28
    var cleanedField;
    for (var i = 0; i < numListings; i++) {

      output = output + '{';
      for (var j = 1; j < 16; j++) {
        field[i] = dom.window.document.querySelector(`#tdSales${i + 1}>td:nth-child(${j})`);
        //some fields have quotes in them  ie> Financial inst or "In Lieu of Forclosure" stated"
        cleanedField = field[i].textContent.trim().replace(/\"/g, "");

        output = output + `"${fieldName[j - 1].textContent.trim()}":"${cleanedField}"`;
        output = output.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

        // don't output last comma
        if (j < 15) {
          output = `${output},`;
        };
      };
      // don't output last comma
      if (i < numListings - 1) {
        output = output + '},';
      } else {
        output = output + '}';
      }
    }
    //output = output + ']';
    output = output.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    console.log(output);
    var obj = JSON.parse(output);
    console.log(obj);
  })();
});
```

Comment: JavaScript syntax is not JSON syntax.

Comment: Also what is the point of building a JSON string if all you're going to do is turn it into a JavaScript object?  It'd be **much** easier to assemble the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with this line `"${fieldName[j - 1].textContent.trim()}":"${cleanedField}"`. Since it is a template literals so `"` is not required

Comment: But I want the quotes to be literal,-I want them in the output. Why are some lines in the output different than others. They are coming from the same code. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not treating them differently, it is just *showing* them differently.

It is using quotes whenever a key contains characters not valid in Javascript variable names, e.g. space or `#`.

The same way that you can write in Javascript `obj.var1` or `obj['var1']` but you cannot write `obj.var2%`, you have to write `obj['var2%']`.

BTW, this output is a text representation of a javascript object, but it is *not* JSON. In JSON, all object keys and strings are enclosed in double quotes `"`. The line above *is* proper JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was copying the output string from the vsCode terminal and pasting iinto the validator (as plain text) Apparently that introduces line breaks. So I saved the string to a file and then uploade4 the file to the json validator and it validated perfectly.